# Change CSS of element within elements and classes

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to set the height of an image to be 50% of the width, but the image scales with the page. The current CSS I am targeting looks like this:

```
.img-quiz p span img { width: 100%; }
```

Here's what I've tried in js, but isn't working:

```
var imgQuiz = document.getElementByClassName('img-quiz').getElementsByTagName('img');
var elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(imgQuiz);
var pixHeight = elementStyle.getPropertyValue('height');
imgQuiz.style.height = pixHeight * .5;
```

Also, I'm new to javascript, do I need to wrap this in a function (i.e. `window.onload = function()`)?

Comment: Can you add this in actual code or fiddle?

Comment: Your js could be running before your DOM/image/css has loaded, so yes, I recommend you make your code a callback to the onload event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this JS Fiddle for help...

https://jsfiddle.net/Lm60v949/6/

```js
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('img-quiz')[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
// console.log( image ); // test to make sure the image was captured
/*
var image = document.getElementById('imgQuiz'); // much cleaner way to select
*/
image.height = image.width / 2;
// console.log( image.height, image.width ); // check the results
```

```css
.img-quiz p span img { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="img-quiz">
  <p>
    <span>
      <img id="imgQuiz" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo--week-old-cocker-spaniel-puppy-630877553.jpg">
    </span>
  </p> 
</div>
```

A couple of hiccups here:

**.getElementsByClassName** and **.getElementsByTagName** both return a HTMLCollection -- to use these, you will have to select the index of the collection that matches your image ([0], [1], [2], ... )
If you can, an ID on the targeted image would be ideal.  Just easier to write and read code.

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('img-quiz')[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```

If you want brownie points, you can do something like:

```
image.onload = function(){
   image.height = image.width / 2;
};
```

(assuming you have the image already captured and saved to the variable "image")
This is a nice sanity check to make sure the image exists (and has a height & a width) before trying to manipulate it.

You may be overthinking the problem a bit -- once an image is loaded, you can just look up the width and set the height property of the image.

There's a couple of extras that you can do here:

- Check to make sure that the image width is not 0 (zero) ... this is a nice double-check that the image has loaded

  if( image.width > 0 ){ ... }
- Round the number down to a whole number (there's nothing wrong with .5 size increments, just nice to work with whole numbers)

  image.height = Math.floor( image.width/2 );

Comment: I ended up using most of the code from this, but it only gets the first class and image, and I need it to get all of them. The page is setup with multiple divs that have the same class, all with a single image in them. How would I change the var to get all divs with the img-quiz class?

Here's what I have:
`function funStart(){
  var imgQuiz = document.getElementsByClassName('img-quiz')[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
   imgQuiz.height = (imgQuiz.width / 2);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", funStart, false);`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7523dnf0/4/ (new JSfiddle for sample code in action)  
The simplest way is to start at the getElementsByClassName level -- you can assign that first part to a variable and later query the number of elements captured ( .length ).  Then just use that info to perform a for loop across all elements caught in the HTML collection.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary of your question:**
My understanding of your situation is, your trying to make an image have the height of 50% of the webpage but its not doing so, you have looked into different methods including JavaScript but struggling, also you asked about onload methods.

If so this is my proposed solution

**Solution**
In this example we are using pure JavaScript (no library or framework)
The html has pre-set the src for the image, if you want to dynamically set the src then use the following imgEl.src = "path/to/file.jpg";

The method or trigger used is a DOMContentLoaded, which ensures all the HTML elements of the page have loaded before it begins trying to read and manipulate the DOM Elements.

The function we trigger is called funStart (Short for function Start), I always encourage people to use abreviations that define the object type so that it is easier to read such as fun for function, str for string, bl for boolean, obj for object, int for integer so on.

inside funStart we are assigning an DOM element as imgEl which is an image obj and we are saying set the width to be innerWidth which is the document width
We are then saying set the height to be 50% of the document height (innerHeight), by dividing the value into 2.

```js
function funStart(){
  var imgEl = document.getElementById("targetImg");
  imgEl.height = innerHeight / 2;
  imgEl.width = innerWidth;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", funStart, false);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="targetImg" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg" alt="background image" title="background">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your feedback, In the past when i have not added the brackets, I have found it can trigger the call before the dom contents have finished loading, this was in Chrome

Comment: I agree with Sam. adding brackets immediately executes the function and doesn't actually register the function as a handler.

Comment: Ah you are right I seem to have confused myself, here, I just checked some code I recently did, I have amended the answer

So we both learnt something here, thanks

It does trigger the function immediately if you add the brackets and doesnt if you leave them off (in this case we need to leave them off)

Thanks guys

Comment: No problem, just thought it was a typo! I have deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example (you can learn more in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)):

```js
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('img-quiz')[0];
image.height = image.width / 2;
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100">
<img class="img-quiz" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100">
```

The HTML file would be like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100">
    <img class="img-quiz" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100">
    <script>
      // you could also move the script tag to the head and add an event handler to the event load (window.onload = function() {...};
      var image = document.getElementsByClassName('img-quiz')[0];
      image.height = image.width / 2;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```